# An arc of one-sixth of the circumference subtends a central angle of how many degrees?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

How do I find the central angle with the following information:
An arc of one-sixth of the circumference subtends a central angle of how many degrees?
Do I just use the formula to find the angle even though I don't seem to have enough information? I'm lost with this one.

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be one sixth of $360^\circ$?

Comment: I think if you draw the circle, its centre, and draw the lines from the centre to the ends of the arc, it will be clear to you: the angle is one-sixth of a full rotation. More neatly, draw the full regular hexagon, and join the centre to the vertices. Around the centre, you will get six $60^\circ$ angles.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you would look for the angle $\frac{2\pi}{6}=\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: @Tony: I think two comments above made the point clear. Right?

Comment: Short and sweet! +